# Maven Failsafe performance?

Tags: maven, integration-testing, surefire, maven-failsafe-plugin

I've started with Maven Failsafe to implement integration tests properly. Previously I was running all tests with Surefire. Now Failsafe runs those Surefire isn't.

When running "mvn clean verify" everything goes well until it's time for Failsafe to run. I don't know in what the configuration of Failsafe differs from SureFire, but almost immediately the system grinds to a halt. Becomes almost non-responsive. It runs the tests, but very slowly.

I'm using the very same configuration of SureFire. Is there something special about Failsafe I'm missing here ? Threads ? Forking ? Bugs ?

Apparently it's related to the junit47 provider. This behavior doesn't appear when it is not used.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>-XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xmx2g</argLine>
      <includes>
        <include>com/foo/bar/**/*Test.class</include>
      </includes>
      <groups>com.foo.bar.testing.IntegrationTests</groups>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same with similar conf, couldn't find why.. after the delay, i also got [The forked VM terminated](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-827) error. Are you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Nope. I fell back to Failsafe's default naming convention of class names ending with "IT". That also works. Sadly I was kind of told to get lost and fix it myself when reporting this problem. So I'm done with this.